# Better tiny format PDF over EPUB or MOBI?

Tags: pdf, epub, web-publishing

I want to write a book. I'll do it without publishing house. I want to produce the printed paper version. I already know LaTeX, so I can make beautiful PDFs.

Since many people have an ebook-reader, I think it would be worth creating an ebook. I can produce a PDF with a very small format (not A4); but not an EPUB so easily.

Is it okay if I publish my book only in PDF or people will not buy my book because they prefer an EPUB or MOBI?

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of this depends on the audience of your book. Some things to think about:

- One of the biggest differences between PDF and EPUB is that EPUB documents *reflow* the content based on the size of the reader screen -- so you can support multiple sizes of devices with one file. Apparently PDF files are larger, but I think this depends on how the PDF is created, and if the EPUB has embedded fonts, etc. See this [SuperUser question about epub vs mobi vs pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/1091041/pdf-versus-epub-versus-mobi-files)
- Ages ago when I worked on kindle devices I found the font and layout support lacking. EPUB does let you embed your own fonts into the file, and most -- but not all -- readers will support the font and render things exactly the way you want. I suspect MOBI files are still not there yet. It sounds like you are interested in how your book renders on readers, so maybe MOBI files are not for you.
- There are programs out there such as [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com) that will convert files from one format to another, for what it's worth.